# ViewDataDictionary vs anonymous object in ASP.net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am a beginner and I am going through some tutorials in my MVC. So, I came across two scenarios.

**Scenario 1.**

I had to pass some data to my view on post and then send that data as hidden field. Here is the code.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordMV viewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
             return RedirectToAction("VerifyToken", new { emailId = viewModel.EmailId });
        }
                                           ^^ USING ANONYMOUS OBJECTS
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult VerifyToken(string emailId = null)
    {
        VerifyTokenMV viewModel = new VerifyTokenMV
        {
            EmailId = emailId
        };
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

**VerifyToken View**

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("VerifyToken", "Security"))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.EmailId)
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Continue</button>
}
```

Works Perfectly fine. I am able to receive values of EmailId. So far so good.

**Scenario 2.**

Needed to open a partial view from Main view, here is the snippet.

Main cshtml file

```
 <div class="abc">
        @Html.Partial("../Widget/Customize", Model.Unit, new ViewDataDictionary() { { "ElementName", "UnitWidget" } })
    </div>
```

partial cshtml file

```
@{ 
    string custWidgetElementName = ViewBag.ElementName;    
}
// some html code below
```

**Observation:** 
In scenario 2 why have I used ViewDataDictionary. Although both example works perfectly fine. But is there any reason that I had to use ViewDataDictionary. In `scenraio 1` can we use ViewDataDictionary? If Yes, then which one is optimum solution.

**Question:** When I need to pass values shall I use `new {key : value}` or use `ViewDataDictionary` or there is no corelation? Instead of `ViewDataDictionary` can I use anonymous object in **Senario 2**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two scenarios are totally different. They are not doing the same thing.

**In scenario 1 when using this line:**

```
return RedirectToAction("VerifyToken", new { emailId = viewModel.EmailId });
```

A new URL is genrated and sent back to the client (the browser) with HTTP Code 301 or 302. When received the browser will re-contact your application wiht the received URL. With that URL, your application will execute the associated action. In your case, the client's browser will call `VerifyToken` action with the `emailId` parameter setted when you call `RedirectionToAction` into `ForgotPassword` action. So using `RedirectionToAction` method is just telling that method to generate a new URL with parameter defined in the anonymous type.

**In scenario 2 is completely different to scenario 1. With this line:**

```
@Html.Partial("../Widget/Customize", Model.Unit, new ViewDataDictionary() { { "ElementName", "UnitWidget" } })
```

You're telling your view to inject the partial view which path is `../Widget/Customize`. Because that partial view the strongly typed, you passed `Model.Unit` as an second parameter. You use also a third parameter `new ViewDataDictionary() { { "ElementName", "UnitWidget" } }` because your partial seems to internally need to access to the dynamic property `ViewBag` or dictionary property `ViewData` of your view.

**Conclusion:**

In scenario 1 you are just telling the client's browser to go to the new URL you have generated after requesting `ForgetPassword` URL. We just call that a rediretion.

In scenario 2, you're just rendering a partial view into a view. The client's broswer doesn't know anything what's going on with partial views they don't know if they exist.

Comment: So I can never use something like anonymous objects in second case?
 second scenario. `@Html.Partial("../Widget/Customize", Model.Unit, new { ElementName, "UnitWidget" } })` and then in CSHTML file `string custWidgetElementName = ElementName`??

Comment: I am a beginner so pardon my ignorance.

Comment: No you can't because Microsoft does not provide an overlaod of `Html.Partial` method that can replace `ViewDataDictionary`.